# Add website to home screen without address bar

Tags: freelancer.com-api

Today  I was browsing "how to migrate jimdo CMS to WordPress" from the internet.
 And I've got a website with some details.
Here is the URL of the website:https://m.freelancer.com/projects/Wordpress/Migrate-Jimdo-Website-WordPress/
When I click over that website's link, after the website is loaded, I saw a window like this: "Add this website to home screen ".
When I choose"yes", the browser automatically created an app for that website in my home page. My Device is android, so I clicked the home button of my phone and clicked over the apps icon. Then an app is just opened. The app doesn't looks like chrome because it doesn't have the address bar. I didn't installed any freelancer apk file.I tried to close and uninstall that app. From home screen, when I hold over the app icon, I saw" remove " text on top of my phone's screen. It means that the app I've hold is not an actual apk. It's a widget or something which is created by the chrome browser by command of that "https://m.freelancer.com/projects/Wordpress/Migrate-Jimdo-Website-WordPress/" website. I want to add that feature in my website, which is a sub domain:sslclive.jimdo.com
Is anyone anyone knows how to add that feature in my website?
That feature must be maid by some kind of HTML/JavaScript code.
If anyone knows, then please answer.
And sorry for my worst bad English

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add this meta tag to tells the browser to launch your page fullscreen

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

You can also add an icon using a manifest:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#launching_a_page_fullscreen_from_home_screen

Comment: I tried this:<button id="goFS">Go fullscreen</button> <script>   var goFS = document.getElementById("goFS");   goFS.addEventListener("click", function() {       document.body.requestFullscreen();   }, false); </script> but it's not working

Comment: I'm trying to add a bookmark button in my website. So that if the visitors click over that button, the web browser simply make a shortcut app which shows my website in full screen view. The app must be created in home screen. If the visitor's device is an android phone, then the app must be created in their phone's home screen, if the device is iPhone, then the app must be added to their phone's home screen, if the do m device is Windows or Ubuntu computer, then I want my website to create an app in the desktop

Comment: If you didn't get what I said, them play visit "https://m.freelancer.com/projects/Wordpress/Migrate-Jimdo-Website-WordPress/" for the first visit, you can see the option to make the home screen app

Comment: Please don't ignore my question I really need your help

Comment: I want two features in my website. One: no address bar (full screen) two: a button to add my website as an app in visitors home page

Comment: Visit: https://www.freelancer.in/community/freelancer-hq/freelancer-mobile-web-app there you can see their article about that home screen app feature. Tell me how to add that feature in my website, after reading that article

Comment: I had to remove the bookmark and add it again after adding this meta tag

Comment: There is a Broken link